# Best practices for analyzing large time traces with high sampling frequency (~ MHz) in R

Tags: python, r, signal-processing, physics, analysis

I'm intrigued by the large number of scientific packages on CRAN (specifically wavelets) and would like to learn how to analyze time traces of typically non-stationary time traces sampled with several MHz with typically 2.5e6 data points.

I usually use Python, but IMHO high-level scientific packages aren't that common (in comparison to e.g. CRAN which offers several different wavelet libraries) in Python (yet) or at least are very new  and often have questionable quality. Even if I decide to only use specific R packages for certain data analysis from Python (perhaps through rpy2), I still have to figure out which data class is appropriate.

## The appropriate data class

I figured I could use the `ts` data class for uniformly sampled data, but I'm not sure how `ts` will cope with such high frequencies as it seems to be designed for data sampled every few months or so. I also noticed that it's common to simply use

```
time_trace <- cbind(t_samples, value_samples)
```

I could also keep the columns in a `data.frame` but I suspect the performance would be sub-optimal.

Is there a recommended approach for such large and densely sampled time traces?

## Handling different time scales

R being very popular with statisticians, I suspect time series are seen and perhaps treated differently than in some branches of physics, where it usually comes down to filtering and analyzing different frequency components (which is usually called digital signal processing). I've noticed that there are some R packages for that, but they didn't seem very advanced.

Would I have to change the way I think about time traces if I wanted to analyze them only in R? E.g. treat them as data to be tested against statistical models with several modes corresponding to different time scales. I'm also not sure how to deal with non-stationary signals.

## Note:

This is not a question about whether R is suitable for DSP, I've created a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543844/is-r-suitable-for-digital-signal-processing).

Comment: "*high-level scientific packages aren't that common in Python*" `scipy` is very established, and `scipy.signal` is what you want to use to deal with signals; R does deal with statistical data, and to be honest, for most signal processing is the wrong tool

Comment: As indicated in the question, I'm mainly interested in wavelets. SciPy support of wavelets is in its infancy. Could you please elaborate on your remark about R not being suitable for DSP?

Comment: I didn't mean to say it's *unsuitable*, but although it might have things like wavelets etc, R's focus is really on analyzing structured data. DSP is also about structured data, but for the typical equidistantly sampled signal, other toolsets might really be much easier to use. If you e.g. look at the developers behind the GNU Radio DSP framework, I know that most of them (including me) use python extensively in both our FOSS and our academic work, but I haven't heard of someone using R directly on the sampled signal; it just isn't very handy for that.

Comment: "it just isn't very handy for that" <- I'm interested in the details.

Comment: Well, you can of course use it to resample things by understanding what resampling of a band-limited signal actually implies, implementing a sufficient low-pass filter for anti-aliasing/-imaging in R, then resample etc. with a program that isn't optimized for this kind of computation.

Or you could just use something that comes with all the signal processing basics in existing libraries and not do that.

Comment: For me, handling a few millions of samples is really intuitive, by applying signal processing "steps" either directly in python/scipy/numpy or by using python to connect GNU Radio blocks that do that signal processing, or by writing such blocks in C++ or python. All the signal specific handling, ie. how to work on parts of that possibly humgous piece of data, and how to shift in and out data between these parts without using up all your RAM are there in other systems.

Comment: I really do think you should use R when R is right -- it's essentially a very highly developed statistics toolkit, but what you're doing is not statistics but signals processing. But it's really set on the idea of working on "sets of measurement points"; as mentioned, a signal is such a set of measurement points, but it really has a lot of additional properties that R just can't take advantage of, because it's not a signal processing framework.

Comment: To be honest, 2.5e6 samples sounds like nothing. I use software that processes samples in realtime, and which can easily do 50MS/s e.g. doing a very intense filter, or even more, if I use hardware acceleration.

My feeling is that it'll be easier to find or port wavelet libraries to python or C++ than to make R do something that it wasn't designed to do, even if someone implemented wavelets for it.

Comment: Let's continue this debate in this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543844/is-r-suitable-for-digital-signal-processing) where I ask you to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to the title the main question is about doing things in R and, while the body and comments suggest there is debating potential for a second entry titled "is R or Python better for digital signal processing" (I'd add MATLAB though), I'll only try to answer the former.

You can keep thinking about data in a tabular format (data frame - one column for your measure/value of interest and one for the time), or have the data in two vectors. As long as you have enough RAM things will be as simple as that. A reasonable machine with 8Gb and a bit of care should let you handle over 100 times more than your 2.6E6 data points.

The R packages [signal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/index.html) and [fftw](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fftw/index.html) are certainly containing good illustrations (in the documentation and examples) for how to go about it.

Comment: I was mostly interested whether there is some specific data structure in R for representing a signal, i.e. tying the dependent and independent variable vectors. `data.frame` would appear to be the natural choice, but I've heard that its performance can be sub-optimal, hence I'm looking for a better data structure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for diverting the "is R suitable for DSP" talk to a different question. I will appreciate your input at [this question I created for this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543844/is-r-suitable-for-digital-signal-processing).